# adding data from php variable to java script variable

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

I got values in

```
var pointsB = <?php echo json_encode($values); ?>;
```

and I want to write them into dataB like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < pointsB.length; i++) {
       var dataB =+ [
           {"loc":[pointsB[i][1], pointsB[i][2]], "title":[pointsB[i][0]]}
            ];
```

But I only get the last value of pointsB in dataB. Is =+ the wrong way? I Thought it adds each value this way. The data is longitude, latitude and a title.

Any help would be nice. TYVM!

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you sure this is a PHP problem?

Comment: The problem is either with the PHP (in which case you should ask a question showing more PHP and making it about getting the right value in `pointsB` which would need you to show us the actual and desired values for it) or it is with the JavaScript (in which case you should show us the value of `pointsB` generated from PHP not the PHP).

Comment: Using the `=+` operator with an array is probably a mistake. You might want to think about what it means or at least `console.log(typeof dataB)` before and after the loop.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `=+` is not doing what you think it's doing, did you mean to do `+=`? If `dataB` is supposed to be an array you would need to use `push`

Comment: `var dataB +=` would still make no sense. If you want to append to a variable inside a loop, then that variable should be declared and properly initialized _before_ the loop.

Comment: i just couldnt made it run, and did a simplier workaround i posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just did a workaround using

```
for (let i = 0; i < pointsB.length; i++) {
   marker = L.marker([pointsB[i][1], pointsB[i][2]], {icon: Icon_l}).bindPopup(pointsB[i][0].bold());
   pL.addLayer(marker);
}
```

which is just adding every dataset into the marker layer and via control checkboxes into the map. the only problem i got is, that i cant use my control.search anymore because i have no properties defined in my marker layer.

sorry i forgot i am using this code to generate markers on my leaflet project.

so if anybody has a idea how i can search in my two feature groups now is very welcome!

my second featuregroup is pK which is using the data from:

```
var pointsA = <?php echo json_encode($values_a); ?>;
```

Comment: to mention: i want to filter/search through pointsB[i][0] of each marker which is displayed via the control.checkbox